# Accessing M2M field elements during the execution of models's save method

Tags: django, django-models

I need to override django models's save method. I have used `filter_horizontal` for a many-to-many field in `admin.py`. I need to access the contents of that many-to-many field in the save method. But the many-to-many field is empty always when save method is executing. So I tried using `Timer thread`, to execute the process little later, but throws up error related to thread. Threads are not allowed in most of server-side technologies to avoid some deadlock problem. Is there any way that I can run a set of code that will execute immediately after save method has completed execution. I read something about `signal.post_save()` that is called in models's `save_base` method but I dont know whether that will be useful.

Comment: I don't think this is going to be very easy. What exactly do you need to do? Maybe we can find some alternatives. For example, the POSTed information is available in `ModelAdmin.save_model` if you need to populate a model field.. The problem here is that `save_m2m()` is called after `ModelAdmin.save_model` and there doesn't appear to be an easy hook to override this behavior.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't access m2m field directly as other model fields(such as `IntegerField`, `CharField`, etc.). Now I am trying to retrieve the many-to-many field values indirectly through form object which is accessible through `admin.ModelAdmin`'s `save_model()` method.

Comment: J.V, you're going to find any m2ms from the current save operation in `save_model` because the m2ms are not even saved until afterwards. My question still stands: what are you trying to do, ultimately? Perhaps there are alternatives, because for example the POSTed form data exists in `form.cleaned_data`

Comment: I am just trying to access m2ms during saving because there I want alter the value of particular attribute of each m2m rows to state that  it is used already. I cant do it in view because the project that I am developing, users will only be using Django's admin section. No custom templates are developed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might want to use a custom model form as here: http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2011/11/29/many-to-many-field-save-method.html
There are a lot of links to related SO questions and bugs there an in the comments.